# Invoke EJB3 deployed on JbossAS7.1 from oracle 11g stored procedure

Tags: oracle11g, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x, java-6, java-5

As part of our application, we have a requirement to invoke a EJB3 SLSB method from Oracle 11g stored procedure.

EJB3 app runs on JbossAS7.1, JbossAS7.1 supports remote lookup of EJB's using its on remoting API's. The Jboss client 7.1 jar is not compatible with the Jdk1.5 VM supported in oracle 11G.

As per my knowledge the Oracle 11G VM support cannot be upgraded, is there any other way to get this done?

How can we access the EJB3 deployed JBossAs7.1 from an Oracle 11g stored procedure?

Comment: Why not expose EJB as WebService and call it from Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found it is not possible to upgrade internal JVM used by Oracle.

So we have used apache HttpCommons to call a spring servlet which did EJB3 Service invocation.